# reordering column in sas

Tags: sas

I am having the following issue :

I have a table which looks like this  :

```
WEIGHT    DATE  8/1/11    1/1/11   5/1/11 ... 10/25/11 
NAME   CLASS
NICK     1        A          .        A       .
JOHN     1       c+         C-        .        B-
JOHN     2        A          .        .        .
MIKE     2       B           B        B+        A
BOB      3       D           C        C         .
...
```

The dates are random dates, and they are not ordered .

I would like to order my dates (my columns) in sas. I looked up some things on google but there is nothing for this particular problem, since I have 300 dates, and therefore 300 columns names.

For you information :

My data originally looked like this :

calendar1 :

```
NAME CLASS CALENDaRDATE GPA
JOHN  1      1/1/11      C-
JOHN  1      8/1/11      C+
...
```

And I used this proc to create my table :

```
    proc sort data=calendar1;
        by  NAME ClASS CALENDARDATE;
    run;

    PROC TRANSPOSE DATA = calendar1 OUT = calendar2 ;
       BY nAME cLASS; 
       VAR GPA;
       ID CALeNdaRDATE; 
    RUN ;
```

Do you have an Idea on how to sort my columns by dates ?

Comment: Migrating to SO because this is off-topic on Stats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a not-so-elegant solution for your reference (some are borrowed from CarolinaJay65's input). You can reorder the column using RETAIN statement.

I don't think you can keep column name like '5/1/11' since SAS doesn't allow "/" in column name. Also the first character can't be numerical.

```
data work.calendar1 (drop=dt);
 input name $ class $ dt $ gpa $;
 calendardate=mdy(scan(dt,1),scan(dt,2),scan(dt,3)); 
  format calendardate mmddyy10.;
datalines;
 JOHN  1      1/1/11      C-
 JOHN  1      8/1/11      C+
 JOHN  1      10/25/11    B-
 JOHN  2      8/1/11      A
 NICK  1      8/1/11      A
 NICK  1      5/1/11      A
 MIKE  2      8/1/11      B
 MIKE  2      1/1/11      B
 MIKE  2      5/1/11      B+
 MIKE  2      10/25/11    B
 BOB   3      10/25/11     D
 BOB   3      1/1/11      C
 BOB   3      5/1/11      C
 ;

proc sort data=work.calendar1;
 by  NAME ClASS CALENDARDATE;
run;

PROC TRANSPOSE DATA = calendar1 OUT = calendar2(drop=_name_) ;
 BY nAME cLASS; 
 VAR GPA;
 ID CALeNdaRDATE; 
RUN ; 

proc sort data=calendar1(keep=CALENDARDATE) out=datecol nodupkey;
by CALENDARDATE;
run;

data datecol;
set datecol;
format col $11.;
col=cats('_',tranwrd(put(CALENDARDATE,mmddyy10.),'/','_'));
run;

proc sql;
select col into :x separated by ' ' from datecol;
quit;

data calendar2;
retain name class &x;
set calendar2;
run;
```

Comment: Nice..I was trying something with PROC SQL since you get to set the var order of the created data set, but forgot about the RETAIN statement. In Enterprise Guide, the default (at least in my shop) option for VALIDVARNAME is ANY...so PROC TRANSPOSE does not automatically substitute the "_" for the "/" in the date values. Once I set VALIDVARNAME=v7, it worked for me. Nice solution +1

Comment: @carolinaJay65 +1 for you too , I work on sASEG and with ValidVarname=v7 it worked perfectly!

Comment: @Robbie Liu Thanks a lot, if you have time can you give some details (or links) to help me understand what the retain statement is doing in this particular case.

Comment: @RickyBobby Glad to help. In this case, RETAIN statement initializes the new created data set with these variables but no value. Then setting a data set will assign values to these variables. The order of variables will not be altered again as it is predefined.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting CALENDARDATE to a SAS date before the SORT and TRANSPOSE procs. You can do the date conversion in your data import.

This code seems to do what you want...(but it is a small sample)

```
data work.calendar1 (drop=dt);
 input name $ class $ dt $ gpa $;
 calendardate=mdy(scan(dt,1),scan(dt,2),scan(dt,3)); 
 format calendardate mmddyy10.;
datalines;
 JOHN  1      1/1/11      C-
 JOHN  1      8/1/11      C+
 JOHN  1      10/25/11    B-
 JOHN  2      8/1/11      A
 NICK  1      8/1/11      A
 NICK  1      5/1/11      A
 MIKE  2      8/1/11      B
 MIKE  2      1/1/11      B
 MIKE  2      5/1/11      B+
 MIKE  2      10/25/11    B
 BOB   3      8/1/11      D
 BOB   3      1/1/11      C
 BOB   3      5/1/11      C
 ;

proc sort data=work.calendar1;
 by  NAME ClASS CALENDARDATE;
run;

PROC TRANSPOSE DATA = calendar1 OUT = calendar2(drop=_name_) ;
 BY nAME cLASS; 
 VAR GPA;
 ID CALeNdaRDATE; 
RUN ;
```

Comment: It doesn't work, If you replace the 3 last lines (with bob) by this one :  'BOB   3      10/25/11    D' you will see that the first date in the calendar will be 10/25/2011 . Your example works because in the sorted table the calendar dates "arrive" in the right order . 1/1 then 5/1 then 8/1 (then 1/1) (then 8/1) then (10/25)